# How to hide a single element in a picker in Xamarin Forms MVVM Prism?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, mvvm, prism

I am using MVVM Prism. I want to hide an element in my picker but. I tried using IsVisible property but it is not working.

HERE IS MY XAML

```
                               <Picker
                                    HorizontalOptions="End"
                                    WidthRequest="180"
                                    HeightRequest="40"
                                    IsVisible="{Binding IsDeductibleVisible, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Deductibles}"
                                    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding DisplayName}"
                                    FontSize="14"
                                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDeductible}">
                              <Picker.Behaviors>
                                    <behavior:EventToCommandBehavior
                                       Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.SelectDeductibleCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=CustomizePage}}"
                                       EventName="SelectedIndexChanged"/>
                                    </Picker.Behaviors>
                                </Picker>
```

HERE IS MY VIEW MODEL. The first record is the record I want to hide. Remove is not an option since the DeductiblesEnum.Zero is being used in a computation.

```
Deductibles = new List<Deductible>
        {
            new Deductible{ Id = (int)DeductiblesEnum.Zero, Amount = 0, DisplayName = "NIL", IsDeductibleVisible = false },
            new Deductible{ Id = (int)DeductiblesEnum.Thousand_100, Amount = 100000, DisplayName = "100,000 per insured" },
            new Deductible{ Id = (int)DeductiblesEnum.Thousand_150, Amount = 150000, DisplayName = "150,000 per insured" },
            new Deductible{ Id = (int)DeductiblesEnum.Thousand_200, Amount = 200000, DisplayName = "200,000 per insured" }
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scenario is removing an item from a list in your ViewModel & you are using the MVVM design pattern. Prism is a framework and won't have any effect over this code. The reason that `IsVisible` property didn't work because it's not the right property. `IsVisible` is a property of the `Picker` and will determine if the `Picker` is visible or not.

What you need to do is alter your `Picker.ItemSource` in order to remove the value you don't want. There are a few ways to approach this issue, but I will show you the most Xamarin approach I'd recommend:

**Use a Value Converter**

Value Converters are a powerful tool for mapping objects in your ViewModel to your UI without writing a lot of code in your ViewModel. After all your ViewModel should have NO knowledge of any views its connected to. [Read about them here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters).

Your ViewModel would look something like this, I have converted your list to an `ObservableCollection` since that is best practise

```cs
// BaseViewModel comes from Refractored.MVVMHelpers
public class DeductiblesViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Deductible> Deductibles { get; }

    public DeductiblesViewModel()
    {
        Title = "Deductibles";

        var deductibles = new List<Deductible>
        {
            new Deductible{ Id = (int)DeductiblesEnum.Zero, Amount = 0, DisplayName = "NIL", IsDeductibleVisible = false },
            new Deductible{ Id = (int)DeductiblesEnum.Thousand_100, Amount = 100000, DisplayName = "100,000 per insured", IsDeductibleVisible = true },
            new Deductible{ Id = (int)DeductiblesEnum.Thousand_150, Amount = 150000, DisplayName = "150,000 per insured", IsDeductibleVisible = true },
            new Deductible{ Id = (int)DeductiblesEnum.Thousand_200, Amount = 200000, DisplayName = "200,000 per insured", IsDeductibleVisible = true }
        };

        Deductibles = new ObservableCollection<Deductible>(deductibles);
    }
}
```

You would then create a new `ValueConverter`:

```cs
public class DeductibleVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value.GetType() != typeof(ObservableCollection<Deductible>))
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException($"Object must be of type: {typeof(ObservableCollection<Deductible>)}");
        }

        var deductibles = (ObservableCollection<Deductible>)value;

        return deductibles.Where(d => d.IsDeductibleVisible).ToList();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("We won't be using this method");
    }
}
```

And add it to your XAML:

```xml
<ContentPage
    ...
    /* Reference the xml namespace for your converter */
    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:YourNamespace.Converters"
    ...>

    /* Add the converter as a resource to your page (or wherever you keep your resources) */
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <converters:DeductibleVisibilityConverter x:Key="deductibleVisibilityConverter"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Padding="20">
            <Label Text="Select your deductibles"/>

            /* Add the converter to your item source */
            <Picker ItemsSource="{Binding Deductibles, Converter={StaticResource deductibleVisibilityConverter}}"
                    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding DisplayName}"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Now you can hide any deductibles you don't want being displayed to the UI but keep them around for your calculations!

[image]

Comment: thank you @Axemasta. it worked! But I didn't used the converter. I only used the deductibles = deductibles.Where(d => d.IsDeductibleVIsible).ToList(); and put it inside to my VM. Thank you so much!